# Why I get Cannot achieve consistency level ONE (Code 4096)?

Tags: cassandra

Why I write to table, I get error:

```
Cannot achieve consistency level ONE (Code 4096)
```

What could be wrong? 
Here is my descriptions:

```
DESCRIBE schools

CREATE KEYSPACE schools WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'eu-central-1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE schools.locations (
    school_id int,
    bus_id int,
    date text,
    unix_time bigint,
    lat double,
    long double,
    round_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((school_id, bus_id, date), unix_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (unix_time ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your write statement, along with how many nodes are in your cluster?  Also, are you executing your write operation from within cqlsh?  Or from within an application or script?

Comment: I found the solution, its related to this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166334/why-i-got-nohostavailable/166341